# No JNI Implementation

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Using **BaseDexClassLoader**, I have successfully sideloaded an activity named Main.

```
public class Main {
    public native void Branch();
    public void Init(Context context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Init: " + "SUCCESS");
        Branch();
    }
}
```

However, the issue I am having is with my native method Branch. It cannot find the jni implementation. JNI implementation can be found if this activity is not sideloaded, but if it is, it cannot. Anyone know of work around?

**Error:**
`No implementation found for void com.company.app.Main.Branch() (tried Java_com_company_app_Main_Branch and Java_com_company_app_Main_Branch__)`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a 2nd module works. Must load new library in sideloaded dex.